# signalR in python, then RecursionError

Tags: python-3.x, api, signalr

When I get the information for signalR

```
from requests import Session
from signalr import Connection

with Session() as session: 
    connection = Connection("https://webquotes-v3.simplefx.com/signalr/", session)
    corehub = connection.register_hub('corehub')
    connection.start()
```

I get

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I don't know what I should do next.

Answer (score 0):

I talked with a customer support of simplefx, and found the problem. 
The server hasn't been active accurately.
Oh,,,
I can't wait for the recovery.